# Why is runAction() function being called multiple times within my update() method?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Within my `func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)` method in Sprite Kit, I have a `gameTicker` that increments by one integer every time the game is updated.

When the `gameTicker` is divisible by 500, I pause the ticker, disable enemies from spawning by removing the original action called in `didMoveToView()`, and start a `nextLevelDelayTicker` that functions as a brief delay. Once the `nextLevelDelayTicker` reaches `100`, I start incrementing the original `gameTicker` again, reset the `nextLevelDelayTicker` to 0, and run an action to start spawning enemies again.

Basically, once the `nextLevelDelayTicker` is equal to `100`, I only want to run the contents of the conditional one time. I added a `print("yolo")` in there to see if it was only being called *once* when the conditional is met, and indeed it is. However, for some reason `runAction(spawnAction, withKey: "spawnAction")` is being called multiple times. As soon as the condition `self.nextLevelDelayTicker.getTimePassed() == 100` is met, an enormous amount of enemies are being spawned within a very short period of time.

How is `runAction(spawnAction, withKey: "spawnAction")` being called multiple times, but `print("yolo")` is only being called once?

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if gameTicker.isActive == true {
        gameTicker.increment()
    }

    // If gameTicker is equal to 5 seconds, increase enemy amount
    if gameTicker.getTimePassed() % 500 == 0 {
        self.enemyAmount += 1
         self.removeActionForKey("spawnAction")

        gameTicker.isActive = false
    }

    // If level has been completed and last ghost has been killed, activate next level scene
    if gameTicker.isActive == false && enemyArray.count == 0 {
        self.nextLevelDelayTicker.increment()

        if self.nextLevelDelayTicker.getTimePassed() == 100 {
            print("YOLO")
            self.gameTicker.isActive = true
            self.nextLevelDelayTicker.reset()

            let spawnAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(
                SKAction.sequence([
                    SKAction.waitForDuration(2),
                    SKAction.runBlock({
                        [unowned self] in
                        self.spawnEnemy()
                        })
                    ])
            )

            runAction(spawnAction, withKey: "spawnAction")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I'm a dodo head. `runAction(spawnAction, withKey: "spawnAction")` wasn't being called more than once, it was:

```
if gameTicker.getTimePassed() % 500 == 0 {
     self.enemyAmount += 1
     self.removeActionForKey("spawnAction")

    gameTicker.isActive = false
}
```

being called multiple times, adding an enormous amount of enemies to the `self.enemyAmount` global variable that was being used to determine how many enemies spawn when `spawnAction` was run.

I added a flag to the conditional and it is only being called once every level cycle compared to what was ~300 times per game cycle:

```
if gameTicker.getTimePassed() % 500 == 0 && gameTicker.isActive == true{
    self.enemyAmount += 1
    self.removeActionForKey("spawnAction")

    gameTicker.isActive = false
    print("STOP SPAWNING")
}
```